# How can I determine the the Wiring Configuration of an LVDT sensor?

Tags: sensor, wiring, lvds

I have an LVDT Sensor for measuring linear displacement similar to the one on the picture. The problem is that I don't have the manufacturer's wiring diagram and they don't provide it, because originally it has a six pin connector. It's a 6 wire LVDT:
Pin 1 - Orange
Pin 2 - Black
Pin 3 - Yellow
Pin 4 - Blue
Pin 5 - Red
Pin 6 - Gray

How can I determine which cables correspond to each of the LVDT's Primary and Secondary Coils?

[image: mechanical and wiring diagram of LVDT]

Answer (score 2):

One pair of wires will bt the primary and no be galvanically connected to the other four wires. Use a multimeter to confirm which they are.

Set up an oscillator on that winding and debug the other wires as per the signal you get from them. The centre tap to one end should give X volts when the armature is central. Ditto centre tap to the other end AND you should get 2X volts across the two ends.

The 6th wire is probably a screen.

Comment: Or just measure the resistance of the coils to determine which is the centre tap.

Comment: So, to find out the pair of wires for the Primary Coil they must have electrical continuity if I check them with the multimeter right? and for the rest of the cables, could you be more specific of how I can test them please?

Comment: Use an oscillator on the primary.... hey I'm just going to repeat myself here. What don't you understand?

Comment: is there a posibility that 3 of the wires are useless? I found the voltages you described and for the Oscillator I'm only inputting a 8khz signal into only 1 wire, and I get the voltages on other 2.

Comment: Also, how do I find the center tap if I Don't know which wires are which?

Comment: The centre tap can probably be found by measuring the DC resistances.

Comment: I'm not an electrical engineer but your suggestions helped a lot, Thanks!